# Powershell replacing periods

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Can anyone tell me if they think there is something wrong with this Powershell script.

```
Dir | 
where {$_.extension -eq ".txt"} | 
Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace “.“,”-” }
```

For each text file in the current directory, I'm trying to replace all periods in the file names with hyphens. Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 8):

As the others have said, `-replace` uses regex (and "." is a special character in regex). However, their solutions are forgetting about the fileextension and they are acutally removing it. ex. "test.txt" becomes "test-txt" (no extension).  A better solution would be:

```
dir -Filter *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.replace(".","-") + $_.Extension }
```

This also uses -Filter to pick out only files ending with ".txt" which is faster then comparing with where.

Comment: yeah, good point. I assumed that renaming the extensions period was the goal ;) +1

Comment: yeah, a bit unclear question, but in windows you rarely remove extensions :-)

Comment: Forget... no, just behave like friend, not mom. ;) He wanted to replace "." in Name - who am I to judge. ;)

Answer (score 7):

-replace operates on regex, you need to escape '.':

```
rename-item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '\.', '-' }
```

Otherwise you will end up with '----' name...

Answer (score 1):

The name property of a file object in powershell is of type string.
That means, you could also use the static string method `replace` like follows and don't care about regex' reserved characters:

```
dir | ? { $_.extension -eq ".txt" } | rename-item -newname { $_.name.replace(".","-") }
```