# how to use windows powershell to clean up (rename) filenames WITHOUT changing the file extention?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, filenames, renaming

on a slightly similar question on here i found this example of a powershell script that renames or better "replaces charakters" within many filenames at once. BUT this might also happen to the file extention itself, which is no good.

So how can i transform this example so that it still renames the filenames, but leaves the file extention untouched ?

here is the Example to replace all dots within a filename with underscore:

```
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "\.","_" }
```

And Question is: how to fix that it is not replacing the last dot (file extention) too ?

Answer (score 3):

You can access the filename minus the extension with the `Basename` property, so you can combine as below:

```
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName { "$($_.BaseName -replace '\.','_')$($_.Extension)" }
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks. but it happened that i just found [this solution here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541980/powershell-replacing-periods) that i like most, because its uncluttered and easy to understand

```
dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.replace(".","_") + $_.Extension }
```

and the nice thing is , that it can be used to clean up additional filename content right away with just a little modification. like this:

```
dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.replace(".","_").replace("nastyKeyword1","").replace("nastyKeyword2","") + $_.Extension }
```

PS:
i pulled my solution from [Powershell replacing periods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541980/powershell-replacing-periods) and modified it to my needs. i dont think this question should be closed as a dupe, because i think the question or problem is not exactly the same but a variant. but if it violates rules, then im ok with it. go for it.

Comment: Glad you found your answer, but you should at least include a link to the solution you found in your answer. Also consider closing your original question as a duplicate.

Comment: i pulled my solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541980/powershell-replacing-periods and modified it to my needs. i dont think this question should be closed as a dupe, because i think the question or problem is not exactly the same but a variant. but if it violates rules, then im ok with it. go for it.  PS PS : was unable to edit my question, so i had to put the Link information here.  :/

Comment: No problem, did the edit for you. I'd say they're pretty much the same question. If enough of the community agree it will get closed as a dupe but will remain open otherwise.