# Powershell, replace DOT with SPACE

Tags: powershell, character-replacement

This works:

```
$string = "This string, has a, lot, of commas in, it."
  $string -replace ',',''
```

Output: This string has a lot of commas in it.

But this doesn't work:

```
$string = "This string. has a. lot. of dots in. it."
  $string -replace '.',''
```

Output: blank.

Why?

Comment: it parses it as regex, afaik `.` is regex for any character

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell replacing periods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541980/powershell-replacing-periods)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`-replace` searches using regular expressions (regexp), and in regexps the dot is a special character. Escape it using '`\`', and it should work. See [`Get-Help about_Regular_Expressions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions).

Answer (score 5):

1. The first argument in `-replace` is a regular expression (but the second one is not)
   `'.'` is a special char in regular expressions and means every single character
   `$string -replace '.', ''` means: replace every single character with `''` (blank char)
   and in the result you get blank string
   So in order to escape regular expression special char `.` and make it treated as a normal character you have to escape it using `\`
   `$string -replace '\.', ''`
2. If you want to reuse your string later you have to rewrite it to a variable otherwise the result will be lost
   `$string = $string -replace '\.', ''`

**So it should be:**

```
$string = "This string. has a. lot. of dots in. it."
$string = $string -replace '\.', ''
```

and then

`echo $string`

results in:

`This string has a lot of dots in it`